# Why do I get "Unsupported extensions disabled" on my extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I did a Chrome extension, successfully published it on Chrome Webstore, a friend installed it yesterday, and today, when launching Chrome, he sees `Unsupported extensions disabled`:

[image]

**What are the usual reasons for that? How to fix it?**

---

Note: the extension is just a minimalist:

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "...",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "css": ["fix.css"],
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": ["*://*/*"]
}
```

and a `fix.css` that modifies the design of certain elements. Nothing else is in the extension. It is still accepted/published on the Chrome Webstore.

Answer (score 0):

This is because extension is not published in Chrome webstore. 
Perhaps installing Chromium browser can help. It should allow to use non-webstore extensions.
There is also bit complexated way to use pre-installed extension described [here](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/pre-installed-extensions).

Answer (score -1):

As recommended in this [page](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/P8d93MZI7lY):

> Try this removal procedure ... http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-discount-buddy-virus/
>   Try running the new [Google Software Removal Tool](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/8L9S6EcWYNc/IStgNLyNDcQJ) ..(Windows Only). Do Browser Reset at end.

You may also check this [Important: Updates on Chrome Extensions](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/d35tIyH8dVM/UGj_iga3x8UJ).

Comment: I can't ask every user who tries to install my extension to do that. Is this popup because of the extension itself (i.e. it may be displayed for each new user trying to install it?) or because of this specific install of the browser?